# How to create a job with Google Cloud scheduler Python api

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I would like to create a cron job that will run every day at 10am to trigger a cloud function. However, I am  having a problem with the Python api. When I create a job it pops out this error.

> TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.scheduler.v1.HttpTarget got str.

Here is my code:

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

project_id = XXXX
client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient.from_service_account_json(
    r"./xxxx.json")

parent= client.location_path(project_id,'us-central1')
job={"name":"traing_for_model",
     "description":"this is for testing training model",
     "http_target":"https://us-central1-xxxx-test.cloudfunctions.net/automl-trainmodel-1-test-for-cron-job",
     "schedule":"1 0 * * *",
     "time_zone":"utc+8",
     }
training_job= client.create_job(parent,job)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `utc+8 is Australia/Perth` and  `job that will run every day at 10am is 0 10 * * *` then the function should be:

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

project_id = XXXX
client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient.from_service_account_json(
    r"./xxxx.json")

parent= client.location_path(project_id,'us-central1')

job={"name":"projects/your-project/locations/app-engine-location/jobs/traing_for_model",
     "description":"this is for testing training model",
     "http_target": {"uri":"https://us-central1-gerald-automl-test.cloudfunctions.net/automl-trainmodel-1-test-for-cron-job"},
     "schedule":"0 10 * * *",
     "time_zone":"Australia/Perth",
     }

training_job= client.create_job(parent,job)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment I am able to create the job :) .

Comment: If my answer helped you , please mark it as accepted for better visibility for the community.

Comment: Could you please tell me why the name of the job is the full path?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing:

```py
from google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types import HttpTarget as Target


from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

project_id = XXXX
client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient.from_service_account_json(
    r"./xxxx.json")

parent= client.location_path(project_id,'us-central1')
job={"name":"traing_for_model",
     "description":"this is for testing training model",
     "http_target": Target(uri: "https://us-central1-gerald-automl-test.cloudfunctions.net/automl-trainmodel-1-test-for-cron-job"),
     "schedule":"1 0 * * *",
     "time_zone":"utc+8",
     }
training_job= client.create_job(parent,job)
```

I haven't tested this code, but it's clear that you're sending the string to the `http_target`, and the instance of it needs to be an actual `HttpTarget` object, and not just a string.