# add body to a cloud scheduler request using the Python API

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm extending off of this question: [How to create a job with Google Cloud scheduler Python api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681672/how-to-create-a-job-with-google-cloud-scheduler-python-api)

I'm wondering how I can insert a body object to be passed along with the function, I can do it via `gcloud`, and I know according to the v1 docs that the body needs to be passed in a `HttpTarget` any time I try to pass it that way it errors and says:

> `TypeError: No positional arguments allowed`

Honestly I haven't been able to get `from google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types import HttpTarget as Target` to work at all.

Can someone give me an example where they successfully used the API to create a job in the Cloud Scheduler with a body (JSON object) sent with it (POST method of course)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
import json

from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

project = "..."  # TODO
location = "..."  # TODO
parent = client.location_path(project, location)

uri = "..."  # TODO
body = {"Hello": "World"}

job = {
    "http_target": {
        "http_method": "POST",
        "uri": uri,
        "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        "body": json.dumps(body).encode("utf-8"),
    },
    "schedule": "* * * * *",
}

response = client.create_job(parent, job)

print(response)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you for helping!